# ethereum wallet and mist both download separate blockchain?

Tags: go-ethereum, mist, ethereum-wallet-dapp

I am on OSX using a mac pro. 
I downloaded and installed mist, before ethereum wallet (ew) on advice from an ether forum. Mist started downloading the blockchain. It took up too much space on my SDD so I moved my home folder to another directory and decided it made sense to have a working wallet first, so I installed EW and it started downloading the blockchain, but to a different location to mist.

To clarify, EW is downloading to:
Library/Ethereum/gethchaindata

Mist has previously stored it to:
Library/application support/Mist/swarmjs/swarm/(long folder name)/chunks

should they not both point to the same geth folder?
If I run mist anew will it download the entire blockchain again, separately? confused. thanks